# SVN file locked by me, now cannot commit it

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

**Scenario**: An binary file needs a svn lock to modify. To modify, the file was first locked, modified, and then while committing, cancelled the commit using the "Cancel" button. Due to some reason, deleted the whole folder containing the locked file (including the .svn folder).

**Problem**: I used "SVN update" through tortoise svn. All the files were updated. But the file which was locked previously does not indicate as locked with the lock symbol. Nevertheless, I modified the file and tried to commit.

**Error while committing**:

```
 Server sent unexpected return value (423 Locked) in response to PUT request for '/****/!svn/wrk/9f89b6b6-7932-9f45-82e8-fafbd5426290/trunk/***'
```

While I try to acquire the lock again using "SVN Get Lock" it fails showing:

**Error when trying to acquire the lock**:

```
.`...is already locked by user 'kr***' in filesystem '/data/svn/dir/***/repos/***/db'`
```

What I feel, is that the lock information on the client side is missing but still present on the server side.

Please suggest a way out.

Version info: TortoiseSVN 1.6.8, Build 19260 - 32 Bit , 2010/04/16 20:20:11

NOTE: Few paths and logins are masked using *

Comment: And a `lock --force` isn't enough to acquire back the lock?

Comment: Why the reputation decrease? The question is a valid one and I researched and tried various options before asking the question. :(

Comment: Don't know. Wasn't me. Here's a +1

Comment: You should have stated you tried options `A`, `B`, `C` and you may have avoided the downvote (it wasn't me, by the way). As the question currently stands it doesn't show much research effort.

Comment: +1, I had the same awkward problem - and all the normal solutions did not pay off.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to [Simon Large](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2009-01/0609.shtml) (co-author of TortoiseSVN):

> Use the repo browser and 'break lock' from the context menu.

Screenshot:

[image: TortoiseSVN 'Break lock' command]

Note that this item will only appear if the item is, in fact, locked. There's also a 'Release lock...' command outside of the repo browser, shown here:

[image: TortoiseSVN 'Release lock...' command]

Comment: Great, this worked. What was rather weird at my end was the file in SVN was locked by another work mate but he had not touched that branch for months!

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? I can't see any "break lock" on my context menu in the repo browser.

Comment: @MatthewLock Sure, I've added it now.

Answer (score 25):

A **Clean up** on the working copy root fixed the issue for me.
I, too, had done a **Cancel** while doing a **SVN Commit**.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, it's in the right click menu under TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal,

```
svn cleanup
```

will break the locks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes back I was using the SVN, You can take a fresh checkout and then merge your changes on that file. Once you merge it you can commit the file to SVN.