# SVN "Already Locked Error"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When trying to commit a change to a repository ( where I am the only user ) I get an error

```
Path
'/trunk/TemplatesLibrary/constraints/templates/TP145210GB01_PersonWithOrganizationUniversal.cs'
is already locked by user 'admin' in filesystem
'/guest/gam/subversion/cdaapi/db'
```

I am the user 'admin'.

I have tried the following, all without success

- running a "clean up" from Tortoise SVN
- checking out a new copy
- using the "repo browser" to break locks, but no locks are shown ( as per [SVN file locked by me, now cannot commit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470730/svn-file-locked-by-me-now-cannot-commit-it) )

  I am completely stuck now as I have a repository now that I can not commit any updates to.

  Any ideas how I fix this

  More Info, as requested :

  SVN Status command yields  ( I have made edits to one file )

  ```
          92       77 admin        TP146228GB01_EncompassingEncounter.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145212GB02_WorkgroupUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP146248GB01_ReferenceURL.cs
          92       85 admin        TP145201GB01_PatientUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145204GB02_RecipientWorkgroupUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145202GB01_RecipientPersonUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145203GB02_RecipientOrganizationUniversal.cs
          92       77 admin        TP145205GB01_PersonUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145202GB02_RecipientPersonUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145203GB03_RecipientOrganizationUniversal.cs
          92       85 admin        TP145211GB01_HealthCareFacilityUniversal.cs
          92       85 admin        TP145200GB01_AuthorPersonUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145207GB01_AuthorDeviceUniversal.cs
      M   92       87 admin        TP146226GB02_Consent.cs
          92       85 admin        TP146229GB01_TextSection.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145204GB03_RecipientWorkgroupUniversal.cs
          92       86 admin        TP145018UK03_CustodianOrganizationUniversal.cs
          92       83 admin        TP145208GB01_AuthorNonNamedPersonUniversal.cs
          92       70 admin        TP145214GB01_DocumentParticipantUniversal.cs
          92       85 admin        TP145007UK03_RelatedEntity.cs
          92       80 admin        TP146224GB02_Atachment.cs
          92       83 admin        TP146227GB02_ServiceEvent.cs
          92       77 admin        TP145210GB01_PersonWithOrganizationUniversal.cs
  ```

A svn commit then yields

```
svn commit --message updates
Sending        TP146226GB02_Consent.cs
Transmitting file data .svn: E195022: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E195022: File    'D:\BENBUN_CODE\WORK\cdaapi\trunk\TemplatesLibrary\constraints\templates\TP146226GB02_Consent.cs' is locked in another working copy
svn: E170007: No lock on path '/subversion/cdaapi/!svn/wrk/3c75d861-8462-b94e-8729-df54843044f9/trunk/TemplatesLibrary/constraints/templates/TP146226GB02_Consent.cs' (Status 423 on PUT Request)
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (423 Locked) in response to PUT request for '/subversion/cdaapi/!svn/wrk/3c75d861-8462-b94e-8729-df54843044f9/trunk/TemplatesLibrary/constraints/templates/TP146226GB02_Consent.cs'
```

As requested output of SVN st -u is shown below

```
>svn st -u
M               92   TP146226GB02_Consent.cs
Status against revision:     92
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After discussing with the hosting of my SVN repository they gave me the following answer.

Apparently my repository is replicated to a remote repository using SVNSYNC. SVNSYNC has known limitations with enforcing locking across the replicated repositories and this is where the problem lies.

The locks were introduced by the AnkhSVN plugin in Visual Studio.

As the locks appears to be on the remote repository this explains why I can't actually see them using SVN commands.

The locks are being removed via the hosting company and hopefully all will soon be well again.

Answer (score 69):

If your SVN repository is locked by AnkhSVN, just use "cleanup" command from **AnkhSVN** to release the lock! ;)

Comment: Amazingly helpful - thanks!  Same deal on Versions.app for Mac.  MERRY CHRISTMAS!!!

Comment: I was trying to check in a folder inside the root folder.. You have to perform cleanup on root folder.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. This problem is easily solved if you issue the Cleanup command from AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 9):

These settings worked for me:

[image: Screenshot]

I was unable to update repository after the connection timeout, while I was checking out the repository.

Answer (score 5):

I am not using AnkhSVN but got a similar problem after cancelling a Tortoise SVN update.  It left two directories "already locked".  Similar to Roman C's solution.  Use Get lock to to lock one file in each directory that is "already locked" and then release those locks, then do a cleanup on the highest directory.  That seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Same here, I had the lock error after cancelling a TortoiseSVN update. For me, doing a 'Clean up' from TortoiseSVN fixed the problem (`svn cleanup` from the command line wasn't enough).

Answer (score 5):

Its even good to use tortoise svn cleanup, no need to use Ankh one in my case

Answer (score 4):

I got similar error msgs. I run svn clean-up, and then tried "get clock" for a few times. Then this error was gone.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine for me, aquired lock by 'get lock', got the error again, runned a clean up on the root directory and got rid of it.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do a Clean Up and elect to "Break Locks" for it to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: I can't commit a lot of files at once.

---

The commit works by:

1. Running a "clean up" from Tortoise SVN
2. Commit each file separate. Create new root folder and commit each file or folder.

---

** If the error returns you should repeat action no.1-2 **

Answer (score 1):

You need to cleanup your tortoise SVN by clicking on cleanup option you get after
Right Clicking on windows where you want to UPDATE SVN.
And after cleanup try updating SVN similarly by clicking UPDATE SVN option you get after right clicking.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,
It was solved when I checked the below checkbox

- Clean up working copy status
- Break write locks
- Include externals

  [SVN Cleanup dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbxH0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN users: right click on the root project directory > TortoiseSVN > Clean up... (*make sure you check all the boxes*). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes cleaning the repository with the "break locks"-option still doesn't work if the lock was created by another process. 
Possible Solution:
1) Acquire a new lock on the folder/file and choose the option "Steal the locks"
2) Release your new lock.